# How can I add an iFrame to Powerapps?

Tags: iframe, powerapps

I'm a UX/UI Designer at a small company and I'm getting trained on Powerapps. Literally have 0 experience on it. How can I, step by step, add an iFrame to Powerapps? If I understood correctly this is the only way to embed a webpage directly into it without leaving the main page.

I tried to download an iFrame component from github but I don't think that is the correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of PowerApps development :)

Fun question but you should provide more details in the future:

1. What kind of PowerApp? Canvas or Model App?
2. What component did you try?  Share the link and how / where you used it.
3. What will be hosted in the iFrame?  Are you going to run into CORS issues?  What is the aim of adding this iFrame?

Here are some pointers, but without more details I don't know if its the right solution.

If its a model app you can do it via the form editor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/iframe-properties-legacy

If its a canvas app you'll need to add a custom component:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/component-framework/sample-controls/iframe-control

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late answer! I've only came back to work today.

I'm on PowerApps Canvas. I didn't try any component actually, tried creating my own from ChatGPT but it isn't an exact science.
I'm trying to host a Typeform page in the iFrame. I tried creating a component, then going in the HtmlText thingy and pasted an iframe in there but it's showing blank, no importation whatsoever.